# Is it possible to see a list of all my edits using a query?

Tags: support, edits, data-explorer, revisions-list

Is it possible to see a list of all my edits using a query similar to this [query for getting a list of comments](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/99/my-comment-score-distribution)?

Can any one give any link to the query?

Answer (score 7):

To see a list of your edits:

1. Go to your user profile
2. Select the "Activity" tab
3. Click on the "revisions" subtab option

Answer (score 3):

Here some queries I found

[How many edits have I made and how much more until I earn the badges?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1024/how-many-edits-have-i-made-and-how-much-more-until-i-earn-the-badges)
[How many edits have I made and how much more until I earn the badges? (v1)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1009/how-many-edits-have-i-made-and-how-much-more-until-i-earn-the-badges-v1)
[How many edits have I made and how much more until I earn the badges? (v2)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1016/how-many-edits-have-i-made-and-how-much-more-until-i-earn-the-badges-v2)
[What posts have I edited that were not mine?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1010/what-posts-have-i-edited-that-were-not-mine)
[What posts have I edited?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1011/what-posts-have-i-edited)

[Top Editors](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/713/top-editors) *(List top 50 editors (counts only edits made to posts not owned by editor))*

Answer (score 3):

In response to [a meta question on Math SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24927/35416) I just wrote another such query: [My edits in post histories](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/533085/my-edits-in-post-histories)

Distinguishing features:

- Only edits (to title, body or tags), not rollbacks and the likes
- Answer includes post type (Q/A), OP, Post title and edit comment
- Links to post and to diff in revision history
- Sorted by date, newest first

Feel free to use and/or adapt this query as you see fit.